# How to auto adjust Font within the Boundary using Fabric.js textbox in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using `Fabric.js` object to create images dynamically in `Node.js`

How do I reduce the font size if the text is too long to make sure that the text does not exceed the blue coloured boundary.

I replace the `{{name}}` from the `textbox` dynamically.

I'm able to wrap the text horizontally. However, it overflows vertically.

I'm using custom fonts, different fonts seem to take up different space.

How do I calculate the upper limit for font size?

[image]

Comment: Does it grow to multiline?

Comment: @aleng yes it does grow to multiline

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with fabric.js, so I just use whatever that I can find in jsfiddle.

I'm gonna use my canvas as max width and max height for the text box. And because you already figure out text wrap for it, I'm just gonna use 'splitByGrapheme' (although I find it behave very weirdly compared to normal word-wrap, but hope this is fine example). Then I made a simple recursion function that check the height of the text box,

```
function adjustSize() {    
 if (textbox.height > maxHeight) {
  textbox.fontSize = textbox.fontSize + 1
 adjustSize()
 }
}
```

so if its height is under maxWidth, it stops scaling down. Not a very fancy way, but it does the work for me. Not bulletproof, but hope it shed u some ideas.

Snippet below I made it run oninput, so there's few extra I made it scale back up again as you delete letters/words

```js
var cWidth = 500;
var cHeight = 300;
var fontSize = 50
var txt = 'This gonna be almost maxed out in height, help me to increase it more! just asdasd asdas'
var text;
var input = document.getElementById('input')


var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
};


var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setWidth(cWidth);
canvas.setHeight(cHeight);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

Addtext()

function Addtext() {
  text = new fabric.Textbox(txt, {
    top: 0,
    left: cWidth / 2,
    fontFamily: 'arial black',
    fill: '#333',
    fontSize: fontSize,
    textAlign: 'center',
    splitByGrapheme: true,
    width: cWidth,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    lockScalingX: true,
    lockScalingY: true,
    centeredScaling: true,
    originX: 'center',
  });
  canvas.add(text)
  input.value = text.text
  onSelectionChanged()
}

function onSelectionChanged() {
  text.text = input.value
  canvas.renderAll()
  input.onkeyup = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if (key == 8) {
      //backspace pressed
      text.set("fontSize", fontSize);
      canvas.renderAll()
      adjustFontSize()
    }
  };
  adjustFontSize()
}

function adjustFontSize() {
  let current = text.fontSize
  if (text.height > cHeight) {
    text.set("fontSize", current - 1);
    canvas.renderAll()
    adjustFontSize()
    return
  } else {
    if (current < fontSize) {
      if (cHeight - text.height < (current * text.lineHeight) * 1.5) {
        return
      } else {
        text.set("fontSize", fontSize);
        canvas.renderAll()
        adjustFontSize()
        return
      }
    }
    return
  }
}
```

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 22px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 99%;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}

.after-box {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js'></script>

<div class="box">
  <textarea id='input' oninput='onSelectionChanged()' rows="5"></textarea >

  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```